# Converting coordinates of point shapefile to another CRS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, point

Basically, I have a bunch of coordinates on a point shapefile that is on WGS 84 (EPSG: 4326) and I want to convert each of them to Greek Grid.

I tried to just change the CRS from WGS84 to Greek Grid when I am exporting the shapefile but it didn't work. So I don't want simply to change the coordinate system I want to convert the numbers of each point is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Field Calculator for that with the transform function, see an example for the x coordinate below:

```
 x(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:2100'))
```

[image]